# Peoplesoft OPRID include in PERSON_BASIC_FULLSYNC Message

Tags: peoplesoft

Some query regarding **OPRID**. i want to include the oprid in the **Person Basic Fullsync** message. I added the record **PSOPRDEFN** to the Message. But i am not able to get OPRID values for all the employees. I am getting only for some employees whose user profile is present.

1. Is OPRID related to only for user profiles?
2. how can i generate OPRID for all employees??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PeopleSoft you have persons (identified by **EMPLID**) as transactional data, and users (identified by **OPRID**) who can access the application.

Not every user is necessarily related to a person or employee (e.g., system accounts such as **PTWEBSERVER**, developers' accounts, etc.), and not every person or employee will have a user profile (e.g., employees without access to Self Service transactions, ex-employees who no longer work at the company, etc.).

So, to answer your questions:

1. Yes, **OPRID** is only related to user profiles (you can obviously find **OPRID** values used elsewehere, like in "Last Updated By" fields, security tables, etc., but it only relates to users). Often an **OPRID** will be linked to an **EMPLID** (in the **PSOPRALIAS** and/or **PSOPRDEFN** tables), but this is neither guaranteed not required.
2. Generating a user profile for every employee is not always warranted, as there are important security implications to it. Furthermore, if your company uses single sign-on with LDAP authentication, the users are automatically created upon first sign-on if so authorized, so proactively creating them is unnecessary and often ill-advised. Finally, it will often be a security breach to have ex-employees with active user profiles, so you may never truly reach a scenario where all your **EMPLIDs** have associated **OPRIDs**. If you've weighed all of these concerns and do indeed want to pre-populate the entire user population, you can use something like Excel-to-CI. However, note that this will solve the issue as of right now, and the moment you create a new employee you'd need to also create its user profile.